# How to check if a number have integer representation

Tags: lua

How to check if a number have integer representation

number can be a float or double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lua 5.3+, use [math.tointeger](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-math.tointeger):

> math.tointeger (x)
>
> If the value x is convertible to an integer, returns that integer. Otherwise, returns nil.

Comment: dont know that really exist because google search give no result about what im asking so i make Q&A about this so people dont need to figure it out by themself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check numbers for dot to see if it is a float or integer?

> Then check this out...

```
dotchk=function(...);
local args={...}
assert(args[1],'Need argument')
local _,b=tostring(args[1]):gsub('%.','') -- Check for dot

if b>0 then
 print('floating point found in:',args[1])
 return true
else
 print('No dot in:',args[1])
 return false
end

end
```

Three examples...

```
>dotchk(math.pi)
floating point found in:    3.1415926535898
true
>dotchk(math.maxinteger)
No dot in:  9223372036854775807
false
>dotchk(math.mininteger)
No dot in:  -9223372036854775808
false
```

Comment: How about `print(1.5e2)` and `dotchk("1.2.3")`?

Comment: ```dotchk(1.5e2)``` works directly for "1.2.3" i suggest under the first assert a second one: ```assert(type(args[1])=='number','Give me a number - Please') -- No number``` - ;-)

Comment: the question doesnt ask for checking whether is it floating number or not
its asking for checking is it has integer representation like `1.0`, `34`, `2.0`, etc